# how custom list inherits the permissions?

Tags: 2013, permissions, custom-list

I created a custom list. Then I created a page (wiki) when I used this list as a web part. 
I'd like to limit the edit permissions for the list (it should be read-only for most users) - so, should I broke the inheriting of permissions on page level and the list will inherit the rights from the page? Or should I manage the rights on the list level? 
What would you suggest? what would be the best solution?
thx.

Comment: No, the page inherits from the page library and the list inherits from it's subsite. Break the permission on the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it on the list level.

As limiting the access to your list seems to be the primary goal, you will want to prevent users from editing the list from elsewhere as well. This means, that if an end-user figures out the list's original source (the .aspx to the list itself), the user would have the non-restricted permission-level still applicable there as permissions wouldn't inherit from a page to a list.

Additionally if you one day want to have some content on the page which the users should be able to interact with (e.g. contribute), the page-level actions for restricting interacting with its elements would cause a headache.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds reasonable. Would it be a good approach as a first setting?: 1. to broke the inheriting for the list 2. add the users groups used on page level to the list level as read-only rights (so at least for now I manage the rights on page level as this will change more often) 3. add additional users to the list that needs more rights (this will change very rarely) ?

Comment: Sorry @Elliss, missed your comment. That seems like an OK approach. Just note that if your user needs to see the list on your page, the user needs to have an access to that page despite already having a read-only (or such) permission to the list.